# What does the word "truant" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> One of the characters in a movie I'm watching is telling a story, about how his mother was murdered in front of him, by his own father. He says that he was found 3 days later by a **truant** police officer.

What does truant mean in this context?

a.wandering; straying.
*"her truant husband"*
(source google dic)

b. One who shirks work or duty.
(source TFD)

Comment: I like _both_ definitions!

Comment: I would expect the phrase to be just "truant officer" rather than "truant police officer", but that may be to distinguish it from a social-services employee, who could also be tasked with investigating truancy.

Comment: Really seems like a case of misplaced adjective.  It's not the police officer who's truant, it's the students the officer is investigating.  Realistically, it should be a "truancy police officer".  Otherwise it's like calling a "homicide detective" a "homicidal detective" - a subtle but very important distinction.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, in common parlance everyone says: truant officer. What confuses me here is it says truant police officer. Which is not usual at all.

Comment: @Dragonel Yes, "[truant officer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truant%20officer)" has a well-established and **very** different meaning from what is intended in the quoted passage here.

Comment: @Dragonel: If the distinction is needed, I'd prefer "police truant officer" (a truant officer who works for the police) over "truant police officer" (a police officer who himself is playing hooky from his police job).

Comment: I've only known them as *"truan**cy** officers"*, not "truant officers"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Truant is also a noun, and I suspect "truant officer" is referring to the noun (which is annoyingly ambiguous with the adjective); so a better example would be "murderer detective" (i.e. what the detective is focusing on, not who the detective himself is). Which is not that far removed from examples like "suspect interrogation". The interrogation itself isn't suspect, just like how the officer himself isn't truant. The interrogation is focused on _suspects_, in the same sense that a truant officer is focused on _truants_.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In this context, it would seem to mean [a police officer who has special responsibility for locating children who are truanting from school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truancy#:%7E:text=Many%20states%5Bclarification,or%20sheriff%2C%20concurrently.), and ensuring that they attend school.

In the US, a school may employ a truant officer who is concurrently a constable.  Their main role is to ensure that the children of the district are safe and attending school.  The truant officer will go to places that children are likely to hide when they are truanting. Then they will detain (not arrest) the child and return them to school or home as appropriate.

So I understand that this child witnessed his father murder his mother.  He was absent from school for three days, until he was found by a constable who had special responsibility for ensuring that children are safe and at school.

Comment: He didn't run away. I just rewatched that scene, and he mentions earlier, that his father tied him to a radiator. But your explanation seems to be the correct one. The truant officer could, after all, come to his house, after he was absent from school for a couple of days right?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this usage, because afaik we don't have truant officers here in the UK, so would have interpreted it as an officer who was not performing his assigned duties at the time ("gone rogue"), but thought it was an odd phrasing. I think your explanation is more likely

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "truanting" used as a verb like that.

Comment: Echoing @Barmar's comment. As far as I know, "truant" is used strictly as an adjective, at least in the US. The students are "skipping school".

Comment: The OED lists "truant" as a verb, but even the definition not marked as obsolete or dialectal doesn't have any citations later than 1879.

Comment: According to ngrams, at least, "truanting" is more of a BrE thing, whereas Americans use "skipping school"

Comment: Yeah, well, a truant officer is an officer who finds kids and makes them go back to school. It is hard to tell here without actually seeing the thing. We say "truant officer". Not truant police officer, and we don't have constables in the US.

Comment: @Lambie: We *do* have [constables in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constables_in_the_United_States), but their job description varies by state, and isn't the same as in the UK.

Comment: @Barmar: Any English word may be verbed, but doing so weirds the language.

Comment: Seems to me the verb ought to be *truate*.

Comment: "to truant" is a perfectly cromulent verb.

Comment: @StaticBounce Correct.  Running away and hiding was an assumption, just change 'He ran away. He hid for three days' to 'He was absent from school for three days' in James' answer

Comment: @dan04 constable in the states is very vague and usually involves criminal matters.

Comment: @Tristan We do have, or at least *had*, truant officers in the UK. These were generally school/council employees rather than police officers though. I suspect they are less common nowadays when you can text a parent whose child has failed to appear.

Comment: @Kevin I'd normally say "to play truant" as the verb